# How to specify single pointcut for multiple packages

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut, aspect

I am using Aspect for logging activities in my spring mvc based application. I am using **@controller** annotations to define any controller in my application. I have two different controller in two different package say

- com.package1 contains controller 1 class, let's name it as AController
- com.package2 contains controller 2 class, let's name it as BController

I am able to apply aspect to one particular package of controllers by using

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="pointcut1"
        expression="execution(* package1.*.*(..))"
        id="policy1" />
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect1" order="1">
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="pointcut1" method="before" arg-names="joinPoint" />
        <aop:after-returning returning="returnValue" arg-names="joinPoint, returnValue" pointcut-ref="pointcut1" method="after"  />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>


<bean id="aspect1" class="com......aspectclass" />
```

My question is how to specify more that one  different package in **expression(* package1.*.***.(..))**.

Right now I am declaring one separate pointcut for each package and in aspect one separate `aop:before` and `aop:after` entry for each pointcut. But I think this should be ideal way to define multiple packages pointcut.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use boolean operators:

```
expression="execution(* package1.*.*(..)) || execution(* package2.*.*(..))"
```

Answer (score 20):

In case you use *Annotations*

```
@Pointcut("within(com.package1..*) || within(com.package2..*)")
```

Answer (score 4):

In spring Boot

```
@Before("execution(* PackageName.Controller.Service.MethodName(..))          
  ||execution(* PackageName.Controller.Service.*.*(..))")
```

Example [Spring-projects/AOP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-aop)

Answer (score 2):

```
  @Pointcut("execution(* pakageName.anyClassNameX.*(..)) || execution(* pakageName.anyClassNameY.*(..))")
  public void allMethods() {
  }

  @Around("allMethods()")
  public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    try {
      return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
     
    }
  }
```